# Create route that returns XML Feed

Tags: 8, routes, page-controller

How do I create a page that returns an XML feed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Can you give more details ?

For example for an aggregator RSS :

In your test.routing.yml :

```
test.rss:
  path: '/rss'
  defaults:
    _title: 'rss'
    _controller: '\Drupal\test\Controller\RssController::content'
  requirements:
    _access_test: 'test'
```

And in your controller :

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\test\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class RssController extends ControllerBase
{
    public function content()
    {
        $response = new Response();
        $response->setContent('<?xml> My flux </xml>');
       // kint($response);
        return $response;

    }

}
```

> You need the HttpFoundation\Response component.

Comment: Just noting, be sure to set the XML content type header or try `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\XmlResponse;` and  `return new XmlResponse($response);`

Comment: This is returning HTML for me with the `<?xml ...>` header being commented out.

Comment: This you'll have Header Content type as "text/html; charset=UTF-8". No good.

Add `$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');` before returning content to fix

Comment: @David Thomas: In which version of Symfony HTTPFoundation did XmlResponse ever exist?

Answer (score 8):

Kevin's answer caused my Twig template's `<?xml ...>` tag to be commented out. I had to add to make the page render it as XML.

```
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
```

Full example for my module named `custom`.

**custom.routing**

```
# My XML controller
custom.my_xml_feed:
  path: '/xml-feed'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\custom\Controller\XMLfeed::content'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

**XMLfeed.php**

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\custom\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class XMLfeed extends ControllerBase {


  public function content() {
    $rows = [];

    $build = [
      '#theme' => 'my_theme_template',
      '#rows' => $rows,
      '#cache' => ['max-age' => 0],
    ];

    $output = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($build);

    $response = new Response();
    $response->setContent($output);
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');

    return $response;
 }

}
```

Comment: There's anyway no caching active for "new Response()", and it should be headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/rss+xml') for a RSS feed.